# Sublime Text 3: bold text in plain text mode

Tags: text, sublimetext3, customization, bold

I'm pretty new in Sublime Text 3, and I know it allows for a wide customization.

I would like to know how I could make some part of the text bold, italic or underlined, or even coloured, when I'm writing a plain text. It may sound dumb, but I have no idea how to do it and whether I can do it.

Thank you!

Comment: You can't do it using plain text, because by definition plain text doesn't have any formatting. You need to use some kind of formatting, like HTML, Markdown, ReStructured Text, LaTeX, etc. Or, use a word processor. Sublime is a *text* editor.

Comment: It makes sense @MattDMo. If I would like to keep using Sublime Text 3, changing the environment from "plain text" to "HTML", how I could set and modify the way the text is displayed? (bold, italic, etc.)

Comment: Alright @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use the [MarkdownPreview](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/MarkdownPreview) plugin combined with the [LiveReload](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LiveReload) plugin to display Markdown text written in Sublime as HTML displayed in your web browser. Unfortunately there isn't anything at this time that can display rendered HTML or Markdown in Sublime itself.

**EDIT** Apparently there is also [MarkdownLivePreview](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/MarkdownLivePreview), which I wasn't aware of before. I haven't tested it yet, but it's very popular, so you might want to try it.